# How do I modify this .SD command in data.table to scale by participant?

Tags: r, data.table, centering

I have this command in R which will scale a group of variables at once:

```
preds <- colnames(d[, 2:34])
d <- d[, (preds) := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols=preds]
```

I would like to modify it in two ways:

1. I would like it to scale each participant's scores separately. I know that if I were not doing to this all columns at once I could add `by = Subject`, but I'm not sure how to do this given the current command.
2. I would like to only mean-center, not standardize the variables.

Comment: With data.table.  you may need `preds <- colnames(d)[2:34]` and in the second line, just add `by = participant`.  For mean center you may need `d[, (preds) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x- mean(x)), .SDcols = preds, by = participant]`

Comment: @akrun Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The subsetting of column names should be more direct instead of subsetting the data

```
preds <- colnames(d)[2:34]
```

Then, we just do the standardization by subtracting from the `mean` of the column specified in the `.SDcols` and if need a grouping, specify the `by=`

```
d[, (preds) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x- mean(x)),
         .SDcols = preds, by = participant]
```